# PHP: How to determine Unix Timestamp of midnight tomorrow?

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I have the following code to determine the unix timestamp of midnight tomorrow.  It seems pretty hacky to me and I wondered if anyone had a more elegant solution.

```
date("U", strtotime(date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime("tomorrow"))));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
<?php
$t = strtotime('tomorrow');
```

You can also set a time:

```
<?php
$t = strtotime('tomorrow 14:55');
```

Please note that, as other date features in PHP, it will use the [default time zone](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) unless asked otherwise:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
$t = strtotime('tomorrow');
var_dump($t, date('r', $t));

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
$t = strtotime('tomorrow');
var_dump($t, date('r', $t));

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
// Generate midnight in New York, display equivalent Madrid time
$t = strtotime('tomorrow America/New_York');
var_dump($t, date('r', $t));
```

```
int(1502204400)
string(31) "Wed, 09 Aug 2017 00:00:00 +0900"
int(1502229600)
string(31) "Wed, 09 Aug 2017 00:00:00 +0200"
int(1502251200)
string(31) "Wed, 09 Aug 2017 06:00:00 +0200"
```

Comment: @Ben James: Nice to know. I've Googled lots of times for the exact specs but there don't seem to be any apart from an incomplete man page and the original C code...

Comment: Well don't I feel like a goof.  Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Depending on your use case you may specify the timezone accordingly, e.g.     strtotime('tomorrow UTC')

Comment: @Greg Important omission, I've just added the information to the answer. Thank you!